# yyplot labels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, label

How do I add labels to a yyplot in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

Here's what MATLAB recommends doing:

```
figure

x = 0:0.01:20;

y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);

y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2,'plot');

set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','left label')

set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','right label')
```

I'd like to add labels to both y-axes of a yyplot without using the axes handles. Is it even possible or do the axes handles have to be used to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the axes handles?  There is a way to get the handles from the figure (using `get(gcf,'children')`) - but its more straightforward (and idiomatic) to just use the handles the way it is intended.

Comment: Got it. For some reason when I was plotting using the handles my data was getting chopped off when I plotted. I have two different data sets that I want to plot together vs. time but the time stamps are slightly different (10 vs. 15 min data set) and one of my data sets was getting curtailed. If I don't use the handles, it was plotting fine but I couldn't label the second y axis...